# Take a specific output in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to search a `.txt` file, `%temp%\OK-%username%.txt` and compare and echo a response. `If file exists do()`, the following command, `dir %temp%\OK-%username%.txt | findstr "OK"`, output return is: `23/10/2020  17:10   0 OK-%username%`.

```
set var=dir %temp%\OK-%username%.txt | findstr "OK"

if %var% EQU "OK-%username%.txt" (
    msg "%username%" test
) else (
    msg "%username%" test 2
)
```

Using echo to `%var%` I got the following return:

```
"dir C:\Users\%username%.CAT\AppData\Local\Temp | findstr "OK-%username%"
```

expected is to return only the file location.

Comment: `if exist "%temp%\OK-%username%.txt" (msg "%username%" test) else (msg "%username%" test 2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a Linux/PowerShell style test -- IE one where the IF statement can contain a command and return it's contents.

That isn't possible in `CMD` using just `IF` and trying to nest the command in one of the evaluated terms will just yield a syntax error.

it is unclear if you want to have this run in a script or directly in the CLI.  Although, if I understand your request it will not differ.

### If I follow the meaning of your question correctly:

You would like to check if "%temp%\OK-%username%.txt" Exists, and take an action depending on whether or not it does this is very straight forward.

```cmd
SET "_File=%temp%\OK-%username%.txt"

IF EXIST "%_File%" (
    msg "%username%" test
) else (
    msg "%username%" test 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easily way to resolve this question is convert DOS language to Powershell, stay with the following commands, i got better result's with powershell, i hope enjoy.

```
$var = Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:TEMP" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($var.Name -Contains "OK-$env:USERNAME.txt") {
    msg "$env:USERNAME" test
} else {
    msg "$env:USERNAME" test 2 
}

Exit
```